# keeping data between parameterized tests with pytest-django

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

I'm trying to put together a series of stories with the pytest.parameterize mark as such:

conftest.py:

```
from django.conf import settings


import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def django_db_modify_db_settings():
    pass


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def pytest_configure():
    settings.configure(
        INSTALLED_APPS=[
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.auth',
        ],
        DATABASES=dict(default=dict(
            ENGINE='django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            NAME=':memory:',
        ))
    )
```

test_db.py:

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


@pytest.mark.parametrize('name,count', [
    ('test', 1,),
    ('staff', 2),
])
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_group(name, count):
    Group.objects.create(name=name)
    assert Group.objects.count() == count
```

py.test output:

```
$ py.test  test_db.py 
============================================ test session starts =============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-3.10.1, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1
rootdir: /home/jpic/src/djcli, inifile:
plugins: mock-1.5.0, django-3.4.2, cov-2.6.0
collected 2 items                                                                                            

test_db.py .F                                                                                          [100%]

================================================== FAILURES ==================================================
____________________________________________ test_group[staff-2] _____________________________________________

name = 'staff', count = 2

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('name,count', [
        ('test', 1,),
        ('staff', 2),
    ])
    @pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
    def test_group(name, count):
        Group.objects.create(name=name)
>       assert Group.objects.count() == count
E       assert 1 == 2
E        +  where 1 = <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager object at 0x7f351e01ef98>>()
E        +    where <bound method BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method of <django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager object at 0x7f351e01ef98>> = <django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager object at 0x7f351e01ef98>.count
E        +      where <django.contrib.auth.models.GroupManager object at 0x7f351e01ef98> = Group.objects

test_db.py:12: AssertionError
```

As you can see, the first test passes which means that one group was created and that one group was left.

In the second test you can see the test fail because the first group is gone.

This implementation works, but we have less detail in the summary because this groups the tests into one.

```
import pytest
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group


story = [
    ('test', 1,),
    ('staff', 2),
]
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_group():
    for name, count in story:
        Group.objects.create(name=name)
        assert Group.objects.count() == count
```

Comment: I think pytest rollbacks transactions (flushes any changes) after each test

Comment: As it should, but if there's a hack i'll take it !

Comment: Try django_db_keepdb mark. It should keep db after test run

Comment: I think this one only disable db drop in test tear down, but doesn't seem to disable isolation between paramatrized tests here.

Comment: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/master/pytest_django/db_reuse.py
Here `test_database_exists_from_previous_run` function checks if there's a db to reuse, and for in memory db it's always False

Comment: I think if you use 'pytest.fixture' you can make the later functions "depend" on the fixtures that come before them and they will hold-off on tearing themselves down until they, and all dependents are finished: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a very quick hack, you might be able to combine the two methods.

```
stories = [
    ('test', 1,),
    ('staff', 2),
]

param_story = []
final_stories = []

for story in stories:
    param_story.append(story)
    append_this = list(param_story)        
    final_stories.append(append_this)

print(final_stories)
>>> [[('test', 1)], [('test', 1), ('staff', 2)]]
```

Then in the paramaterize mark:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('name,count', final_stories)
```

I'm not sure how to go from `name,count` to a list of lists, however. Perhaps `[name, count] * len(final_stories)`?